# ¿Como borrar un archivo local sin afectar github?

Tags: git, github

perdon si es una pregunta obvia pero soy nuevo. Entiendo para que sirve git y github. Pero mis dudas son dos.

La primera esta relacionada con el titulo, queria saber si se puede borrar un proyecto localmente pero que siga estando en github. Mas que nada porque estoy practicando y quiero tener algunos proyectos en la nube pero no localmente.

La segunda esta relacionada con el uso de git. Cada vez que haga un cambio tengo que usar los comandos de git? Les pongo un ejemplo extremo: Escribo un `<h1>` (aplico los comandos git) escribo un `<p>` (aplico los comandos git) y asi en cada momento?

Disculpen si la pregunta es tonta pero necesito sacarme estas dudas. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes borrar un archivo en local pero todo lo que borres o edites se va registrando en *git*, los comandos de *git* los aplicas cuando terminas una determinada tarea pueden ser varios archivos editados o borrados. Una ves realices un *commit* y *push* todo lo que hiciste en local se subirá a tu repositorio ya sea servidor o github. Si no quieres que algún archivo se vea afectado  para modificación o edición debes especificarlo en el archivo **`.gitignore`**. Saludos ;)

Comment: Entiendo que preguntas acerca de la eliminación de un proyecto local _completo_. Es perfectamente posible. Basta borrar la carpeta que contiene ese proyecto (dentro de ella hay otra carpeta oculta llamada `.git` que contiene todo el historial de versiones, que se borraría también). Borrar esas carpetas localmente no afecta al repositorio en github que por supuesto sigue existiend, y que siempre puedes usar para recuperar una copia local del mismo mediante un `git clone`

Comment: Respecto a lo segundo, eres tú quien elige la _granularidad_ de cada commit. Es decir, puedes elegir hacer un commit a cada mínimo cambio (no recomendable), o hacer uno solo tras una semana de trabajo, que incluya miles de cambios (tampoco nada recomendable). Lo habitual es agrupar cambios relacionados entre sí en un solo commit, de modo que el mensaje de commit sea claro. Por ejemplo "Corregido bug #23 en index.html". Un commit con esa descripción puede incorporar múltiples cambios en varias líneas, pero forman "un grupo" o unidad apropiada para ir en un solo commit.

Answer (score 0):

Para futuras referencias: GitHub es una aplicación que, en rigor, contiene repositorios de trabajo, que en la práctica, se traduce como una copia de tu trabajo local. El comportamiento típico de interacción es establecer un repositorio en GitHub como origen en el campo `remote.origin.url` declarado en tu archivo `.git/config` en la carpeta de trabajo. Lo puedes encontrar como:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url_remota>
```

Siendo `<url_remota>` la dirección explícita del repositorio remoto, es decir, el link de tu repositorio en GitHub. Por ejemplo:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/miNombreDeUsuarioOEquipo/MiProyecto.git
```

Por defecto, GIT crea un [branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) (o rama) llamado `master`. Ahora bien, considerando esta configuración fundamental, debemos tener claro que GIT dependende fundamentalmente, y de manera simplificada, de un índice de cambios, los cuales se definen con [commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), básicamente, puntos de guardado que generan una versión etiquetda con hexadecimal específico y único en el branch (ejemplo: `bacdf95099e8b319d753736be0ecbf5ae51a08e2`). Estos cambios son siempre contenidos de manera local, por lo que no se ven reflejados hasta que dichos cambios son añadidos al índice remoto.

Considerando estos puntos, la respuesta a tu primera pregunta:

> La primera esta relacionada con el titulo, queria saber si se puede borrar un proyecto localmente pero que siga estando en github. Mas que nada porque estoy practicando y quiero tener algunos proyectos en la nube pero no localmente

Es: Sí, siempre y cuando los respectivos commits hayan sido agregados al repositorio de GitHub. Es decir, que hayas hecho un [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) desde tu repositorio local en tu computadora. Habiendo hecho esto último, el repositorio debería tener la última versión de tu branch que, si no has creado otro, sólo sería master, por lo que tu repositorio completo estaría respaldado en GitHub.

---

Por otro lado, el comportamiento típico de GIT no considera guardar ni publicar los cambios en tiempo real, por lo que cualquier manipulación básica de un archivo o carpeta debe ser guardada, agregada al registro de cambios y publicada de forma manual.

Básicamente, tendrías que ejecutar estas tareas después de modificar tus archivos locales:

- [add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) si es que se agrega un archivo nuevo
- [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)
- [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Por lo que la respuesta a tu pregunta:

> La segunda esta relacionada con el uso de git. Cada vez que haga un cambio tengo que usar los comandos de git? Les pongo un ejemplo extremo: Escribo un <h1> (aplico los comandos git) escribo un <p> (aplico los comandos git) y asi en cada momento?

Es: Sí. Tendrías que ejecutar las tareas básicas antes mencionadas cada vez que guardes los cambios, haciendo especial incapié en que el `git push` es fundamental para que esos cambios se almacenen en el repositorio remoto (GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

la respueata corta y amplia (o sea, aplica para muchas otras preguntas) es: lo que va a quedar en github es lo que colocas in el índice, acometes en la revisión y finalmente empujas.

Si tu borras un archivo *localmente* y ese cambio no forma parte de lo que se acomete, eso no se va a ver reflejado en github.

Para este caso específico en el que se quiere borrar un archivo, puedes borrar el archivo localmente *fuera de git*.... o sea, con tu manejador de archivos preferido. Lo que va a suceder es que al hacer status, git te va a decir que el archivo está borrado.... y si te equivocas al hacer un `git add` más adelante, la borrada se va a incluir en el indice y se acometería, cosa que quieres evitar. Si no quieres que git se vuelva a molestar en mirar ese archivo borrado y evitar que la borrada termine en el repositorio, podrías indicarle a git que asuma que el archivo no se ha modificado:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged el-archivo
```

Este ajuste es *local* y mas nadie lo va a recibir. Todas las demas personas que trabajen con otros repos van a seguir viendo ese archivo con total normalidad.